# How to access current user on doctrine's postLoad Event?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony5

I'm trying to create a listener which has the postLoad event, in which I need the current user. No matter if I try using TokenStorageInterface or Security, both return null.

Here's my services.yaml

```
    entity_encryption_listener:
        class: 'App\EventListener\EntityEncryptionListener'
        arguments:
            - 'secret_key'
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
```

and my EntityEncryptionListener

```
class EntityEncryptionListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $security;
    private $secret;

    public function __construct($secret, Security $security)
    {
        $this->secret = $secret;
        $this->security = $security;
    }
    
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [Events::prePersist, Events::preUpdate, Events::postLoad];
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->getSecret();
        $this->encryptEntity($args);
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->getSecret();
        $this->encryptEntity($args);
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        //dd($user);
        $this->getSecret();
        $this->decryptEntity($args);
    }
```

But $user still returns null... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found another way.
I use the session to get the user object:

```
public function __construct(private readonly RequestStack $requestStack)
{
}


public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
{
    $connectedUser = (unserialize($this->requestStack->getSession()->get('_security_[YOUR FIREWALL]'))); 
     //... 
 }
```